# How does InputStreamReader.close() work internally?

Tags: java, file-io

It seems that the actual `close()` implementation is tucked away somewhere in the hierarchy of base classes and implementations of abstract methods. For example, are you guaranteed that the file descriptor gets released? Here is the closest thing to what I wanted to know:

```
   nd.preClose(fd);
   long th;
   if ((th = readerThread) != 0)
   NativeThread.signal(th);
   if ((th = writerThread) != 0)
   NativeThread.signal(th);
   if (!isRegistered())
   kill();
```

from [`DatagramChannelImpl`](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/sun/nio/ch/DatagramChannelImpl.java.html). Can anyone translate into English?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So every time I source dive <strike>Sun</strike> Oracle's Java code I am disappointed. *nd* as a variable name? Does not get more opaque than that.

What *nd* is referencing is [NativeDispatcher](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/sun/nio/ch/NativeDispatcher.java.html) which handles platform specific operations, such as closing File Descriptors (kindly named the variable *fd*). I can only assume the [NativeThread](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/sun/nio/ch/NativeThread.html) check and signal is to clean up the read/write threads, the source does not lend much information. The `isRegistered()` from [AbstractSelectableChannel](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/java/nio/channels/spi/AbstractSelectableChannel.java.html) makes sure the Channel is not being used and the `kill` method is what closes everything down and finally calls the *nd.close(fd);*

Answer (score 0):

From the Javadoc: "Closes the stream and releases any system resources associated with it". The file FD is a system resource. Ergo it gets closed.